# APM tag removed. What is the rationale?

Tags: discussion, tags

It appears the "APM" tag has recently been removed from the system. (APM means Actions Per Minute.)  A quick search for "APM" gives 44 search results. APM is relevant to at least the RTS (real time strategy) genre. APM is tag that isn't specific to one game.

What are the reasons for the removal of the APM tag?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I removed it because it was only attached to two questions and it doesn't strike me as a particularly useful subdivision of questions.

Furthermore of the [44 search results for 'APM'](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=apm), 40 of them are tagged [starcraft](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft) or [starcraft-2](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/starcraft-2). Of the other 4, one is a question about a [BF2142 unlock that happens to share the acronym](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/18366/how-do-i-assault-a-titan-with-a-new-character-in-bf2142), one is [a question about a mechanic in Rift](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/17329/contribution-in-rift-invasions-rifts-footholds-and-other-events) which is based upon 'Actions per minute', but not in the same way that it's defined in a strategy game, and finally, we have *one* [question about broader RTS strategy](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/57172/how-can-i-become-a-better-strategy-rts-player), in which APM is only passingly referenced, and a [question about keyboards](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/14396/zboard-keyboard-for-pc) where APM is referenced as a metric for high usage.

Quite frankly, the tag doesn't add anything to the site that I can see, and I don't feel that there's any real cross-game expertise on 'APM' that we're missing out on appealing to by not having the tag.

Comment: Thanks for the response. I just realised that I don't actually understand the use of tags vs search here. Where can I find more information on the criteria and philosophy for the tagging system here? I can't seem to find anything describing the tag system in detail.

Comment: To be honest, our tags are kind of a mess. The only *real* consensus we have is that game title tags are the best thing we can do in most cases. Beyond that, there's a growing consensus that *most* other tags are, while not useless, unworkable. We have a lot of 'legacy' tags like [tag:endings] that are 'bad tags' by most accounts, but are difficult to remove without causing other problems, so my removal of APM was an attempt to nip a similar problem in the bud. For more, [meta-tag:tags] is a good place to start reading up.